# Why does a glob with unquoted variable expand to all files?

Tags: bash

I have this short snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

touch a_b c_d e_f

p=a

printf '%s\n' "Not quoted" ./$p_*
printf '%s\n' "" "Quoted" ./"$p"_*
```

**Output:**

```
Not quoted
./a_b
./c_d
./e_f

Quoted
./a_b
```

I am well aware of word-splitting and the dangers of not quoting variables but I do not understand why the first glob, with the unquoted variable `$p`, expands to all files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_` is a valid part of a variable name in bash. So your unquoted one is actually expanding `$p_`, which is an empty variable.  That makes your `printf` line look like:

```
printf '%s\n' "Not quoted" ./*
```

And the `*` expands to all the files as you'd expect.

You'll get the behaviour you expect if you put the optional braces around your variable name:

```
printf '%s\n' "Not quoted" ./${p}_*
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me that the quotes actually separate the variable name from the `_`...I need a coffee.

Comment: @mickp Shellcheck would have warned you about `p_` being referenced but not assigned ;)